# Vue-Select: Pushing a 2 dimensional array to :options

Tags: vuejs2, vue-select

The plugin [Vue-Select](https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/docs/).

What I was trying to do is, make a search-select-dropdown input based on database.

So here's my SQL first named **Ms_Location.**

```
id_Loc | name_Loc
LOC0001 | Indonesia
LOC0002 | China
LOC0003 | America
```

My **index.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
</head

<body>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lokasi_id" class="control-label required"><strong>Lokasi</strong></label>
    <v-select :options="lokasi_list" placeholder='Type location..'></v-select>
  </div>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest"></script>

  Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);
  
  var app = new Vue ({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                lokasi_select: '',
                lokasi_list: [],
            },
            // End of data

            computed: {
                get_lokasi() {
                    var list_loc = new Array();
                    list_loc = <?php include('receive_lokasi.php') ?>;
                        for(var i=0; i<list_loc.length; i++) {
                            var pushLoc = {
                                label: list_loc[i][1], value: list_loc[i][0]
                            }
                            this.lokasi_list.push(pushLoc);
                        }
                    return list_loc[0][1];
                }
            }

        })
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my **receive_lokasi.php**

```
    <?php
    include ('koneksi.php');

    $condition = "1";
    if(isset($_GET['userid'])){
        $condition = " id=".$_GET['userid'];
    }

    $sqltran = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id_Loc, name_Loc FROM ms_location")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $response = array();

    while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran,MYSQLI_NUM)) {                         

        $response[] = $rowList;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

However, I can't seem to get the option shown. This only happens after I make the **get_lokasi().** So the mistake is probably there? Or perhaps I was missing something.

I've tried to print the lokasi_list somewhere, and yes, the value is there, but not shown in the dropdown bar.

Also, I'm new to Vue, so any help would be good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind..

My mistake, I didn't notice my `receive_lokasi.php` code

Instead of using MYSQLI_NUM

```
while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran,MYSQLI_NUM)) {                         
$response[] = $rowList;
}
```

I should be using **MYSQLI_ASSOC,** as documented in [here.](https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/docs/Basics/Options.html)

```
while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran,**MYSQLI_ASSOC**)) {                         
$response[] = $rowList;
}
```

After that change this

```
<v-select :options="lokasi_list" placeholder='Type location..'></v-select>
```

To this

```
<v-select label='nama_Location' :options="lokasi_list" placeholder='Type location..'></v-select>
```

After that, everything loads fine.

Answer (score 0):

Vue's computed properties aren't normally used to populate vue data attributes, they normally take one or more data attributes and combine them into something different for the template to use.

In your code you've tried to populate the vue data attribute 'lokasi_list' in the computed property 'get_lokasi', but you never call 'get_lokasi' anywhere in the template so lokasi_list remains empty.

Another approach to this sort of situation is to use a vue method to fetch data from the php backend via an ajax call with something like axios, and you'd normally use that method in the vue app's created life cycle event to get the data asap.

e.g.

```
<script>
    Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);

    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        lokasi_select: '',
        lokasi_list: [],
      },
      created: function() {
        this.fetchLocations();
      },
      methods: {
        fetchLocations: function() {
          axios.get('/api/locations-end-point')
            .then((response) => {
              this.lokasi_list = response.data //might need to change this to match how your php is returning the json
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              //handle the error
            })
          }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Sorry to mention this, but in your php you've got:

```
if(isset($_GET['userid'])){
    $condition = " id=".$_GET['userid'];
}
```

That looks like you were planning to use it as part of your sql, but it would have been vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, sorry If I'm pointing out something you already knew.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your answer, let me try using Axios and tell you how it goes. And about the php files. It's fine, I'm aware of security issues about the web I'm building, however I'm still learning about it and doesn't know what to do about web security yet.. but since this web is only for my own project and wouldn't be hosted online, I didn't worry about it. Thanks for the heads up Richard!